# KnockoutJs not looping through my observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, javascript-objects

**My Problem**

I am trying to populate a table by looping through JSON I am getting from server. This is what is being displayed to me:

**Screenshot**
[image]

**JSON**

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "firstName": "john",
            "lastName" : "Smith",
            "email":"jmith@gmail.com",
            "phone":"800-555-1212",
            "role":"Admin"
        },
        {
            "id": "678",
            "firstName": "Mike",
            "lastName" : "Brown",
            "email":"mbrown@gmail.com",
            "phone":"800-777-1212",
            "role":"Admin"
        }

    ]
}
```

I have followed the tutorial on Knockoutjs.com regarding this foreach statement, and still not getting the results they show.

This web form here is telling me I have too much code in my question, so here is a link to the page in question, so you can see my table HTML:

**Link To Page Online**
http://johntesting.azurewebsites.net/knockout/users-list.html

**My ViewModel**
Here is the view model in question:

```
  /* CLASS User 
   * @param  id             int     unique id project

   */
  var User = function(id, firstName, lastName, username, email, password, phone, role) {

    this.id            = ko.observable(id);
    this.firstName     = ko.observable(firstName);
    this.lastName      = ko.observable(lastName);
    this.username      = ko.observable(username);
    this.email         = ko.observable(email);
    this.password      = ko.observable(password);
    this.phone         = ko.observable(phone);
    this.role          = ko.observable(role);

  };

// User View Model
var UserViewModel = function () {

    self = this;

    /* Constants */


    /* Observables */
    self.firstName = ko.observable();
    self.lastName = ko.observable();
    self.userName = ko.observable();
    self.email = ko.observable();
    self.password = ko.observable();
    self.confirmPassword = ko.observable();
    self.phone = ko.observable();
    self.role = ko.observable();



    /* Observable Arrays */
    self.users = ko.observableArray();

    /* Computed Observables */
    self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
    }, self);

    /* Methods */

    self.init = function () {
        self.getAllUsers();
        console.dir(self.users());
    }

    /* Get All Users */
    self.getAllUsers = function() {
        $.getJSON(Evolve.apiBaseUrl, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, users) { 
                self.users.push( new User(
                    users.id,
                    users.firstName,
                    users.lastName,
                    users.username,
                    users.email,
                    users.phone,
                    users.role
                ) ); 
            });

        })
    }



    self.init();



}; // End View Model


ko.applyBindings(new UserViewModel());
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this is not displaying?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error I found the answer on my own:

It had to do with how I was creating the object. For those who may need this answer, here is what I used:

```
 self.getAllUsers = function() {
        $.getJSON( "./js/json/index.json", function( data ) {
            //JSON EXPECTS id, firstName, lastName, username, email, password, phone, role;
            $.each( data.users, function( key, val ) {
              self.evolveUsers.push( new User( val.id, val.firstName, val.lastName, val.userName, val.email, val.password, val.phone, val.role));
            });

          });
    }
```

and then the traditional foreach working in my HTML.